# stripe + react native transferring money between accounts

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am developing a mobile app with react native. A Sender will transfer money to my app. The app will hold the money, and then that money will be transferred to a Reciever's account. Can I use stripe to hold that money and for all this transaction? If not, how can I achieve this using stripe and react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Stripe for that type of flow. The specific product you'd need to use is Stripe Connect, which you can read more on here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect

The basic idea is that you would have a Stripe account for your app, and you would create Connected Stripe accounts for your Receivers. From your app you can charge the sender and immediately transfer the full amount to the Receiver account. You can also optionally take a small cut or fee from the transaction. You can read more on the types of charges possible with Connect here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Stripe doesn't have a React Native library, but you can use tipsi-stripe which is the most popular library for collecting payment details for use with Stripe:

https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

Another option would be to host a web form in a React Native WebView and use Stripe Elements or Stripe Checkout:

- https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview
- https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment